# Linking to and using libpq with Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-c++

I am trying to access from Visual C++ 2010 Express a Postgres database.  I have both on my machine but the SQL calls do not work at all.   I have searched many sites.  I think that this version of Express does not have any default database connections  like the non-express version (especially Visual  C++ 2008).

The only thing I could find was the following link and I have following the modifications to the Project Properties  area of Visual C++  Express.

http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example/

When I try to run the C++ code in that website I get errors indicating that it cannot find the functions.

Do you have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?  Would it be better for me to use something other than Visual C++ Express 2010 to connect to a postgres db?   One of the other Express versions?  The regular (non-express) Visual C++?

Thanks

Comment: Visual C++ Express 2010 is good enough. Works for me with [pgstream](https://github.com/manitou-mail/pgstream) by doing basically as in the tutorial you mention. You should add to your question the actual error messages copy-pasted from Visual.

Comment: You question indicates you're building ok, but run-time goes kerflush, is that accurate (and can you provide the error messages you're seeing  regardless)?

Comment: Please show your project configuration (or any part of it that mentions libpq) and the *exact text* of any error messages. Copy and paste them.

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  The problem was that I was adding directories in Visual C++ Express that are in the x64 area.  I forgot that Windows 7 now has the Program Files area as x64 and the x86 area is the one I wanted to include in Visual C++ Express.    Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also be interested in [libpqtypes](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/) and [libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/) if you're working with PostgreSQL and libpq. The first provides greatly simplified access to data values from libpq, and the latter provides a more C++-friendly interface.

As for the errors, most likely:

- Your include path or link library path is wrong if it's failing at compile-time or link time; or
- Your PATH doesn't include libpq, if it's failing at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (you didn't provide any actual error messages) the problem is your setup. You need to add the correct header ("include") directory and library directory; if you just copied them from some tutorial, make sure they actually point to the real place where these files (.h and .lib files, respectively) are.

Comment: I think he's compiling fine. After reading his question, he appears to be having run-time issues (i.e. likely his program has no path to support DLL's if he's using a non-static-lib build model.

Answer (score 1):

You need do recompile the libpq with MSVC (nmake /f win32.mak all), after that, you need to set your project to use that library, and change the Common Language Runtime Support to (/clr) and not to clr/pure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It did work wihout that.  I used postgres 9.2 so there were some minor changes in the directories but I did not need to recompile libq.  9.2 might have the one for windowws.